# Use of Mage::getUrl() array parameter

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

Before I used to do this:

```
$response['url'] = Mage::getBaseUrl() .'module/controller/action?sku=' . $request['sku'] . '&qty=';
```

Now I am required to use `::getUrl()`, but I can't seem to understand how to make use of the reserved special values ([tutorial here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/reference/geturl_function_parameters)).

So now I do this:

```
$response['url'] = Mage::getUrl('module/controller/action', array('sku_query' => $item['sku'], 'qty_query' => ''));
```

and my url string comes out like this: `...module/controller/action/sku_query/skuValue/` 
instead of with `?` and `&` for the GET query strings. And also the `qty` is missing...

Whereas, I want it to look like `...module/controller/action?sku=skuValue&qty=`

---

*Screenshot from the debugger, to check the value of the url:*
[image: screen shot from the debugger]

*How the code looks:*

```
Mage::getUrl('orderbysku/producttype/showpopupinproductviewpage', array('_query' => 'sku='.$item['sku'].'&qty='))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
Mage::getUrl(
    'module/controller/action',
    array('_query' => 'sku=' . $item['sku'] . '&qty=')
);
```

Comment: Wow, I thought they'd have done it in a smarter and more clear way, that you can distinguish each attribute of the array, but anyway... 
Though there's the problem now, that it puts `/` even after the action name, so now the url is `.../action/?sku=value&qty=` and there shouldn't be slash before the beginning of the query string.

Comment: @Syspect. That's not possible because of this code in `Mage_Core_Model_Url::getRoutePath()`. `if ($routePath != '' && substr($routePath, -1, 1) !== '/') {
                $routePath .= '/';
            }` So if the url does not end with a slash it adds it

Comment: I updated my post with 2 screen shots, so you can check it out.

Comment: And the strange thing is that it works even when there's a slash before the query string... O.o

Comment: Then maybe I misunderstood your problem. I thought you know it works with the slash. I suggest you leave it like that. With a slash

Comment: Haha, yeah. I didn't know it works with a slash. Then I tested more and I was amazed that it works. I tested with more urls cases, that are set by default, and I saw that they're all with slash before the query string. Every day you learn something new... :D